# Using php to consider user input in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

Consider I have a simple form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
      <input id='textsearch' type="text" placeholder="Enter a character" name="search">
      <button onclick="addfields()">Add</button>
</form>
```

Here, as the user click the Add button, the `onclick` event is triggered and `addfields()` function gets activated. In that function, I have somehow managed to add one input field in this form and the form now looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
      <input id='textsearch' type="text" placeholder="Enter a character" name="search">
      <input id='textsearch_1' type="text" placeholder="Enter a character" name="search_1">
      <button onclick="addfields()">Add</button>
</form>
```

But, there has been a problem. If I use php to get access to these variables, I can use something like this:

```
<?php
$first_char=$_POST["search"];
$second_char=$_POST["search_1"];
?>
```

But where does it end? I have no prior idea how many fields the user creates and inputs data in those fields. Then, how can there be a solution to that?

NOTE: I know using `onclick()` function is much disapproved by many users. I am still stuck to this bad usage habit. Apologies for that. Thank you.

Comment: you need to submit your form i.e name as an array like name="search[]" . On your php code you just need a single variable  for instance $search = $_POST["search"] then loop through and you will be able to store to the db.

Comment: @NelsonSammy So can I keep the name of the second input field as `search_1`? Or do  rename it to `search`?

Comment: it needs to be search, can you submit your js I write for you a good answer

Comment: Your question seems a bit confusing. Do you want to dynamically generate N number of textbox and not sure how many text boxes will the end user will be submitting to backend page? Or something else?

Comment: @FreeKrishna Yes, I want to generate N number of textbox and want to preserve data from all of them. The textboxes would be generated by the user himself.

Answer (score 2):

According to @Nelson Sammy, you can try this concept instead

HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
      <input id='textsearch' type="text" name="search[]">
      <input id='textsearch_1' type="text" name="search[]">
      <button onclick="addfields()">Add</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$search_text_array=$_POST["search"];

print_r($search_text_array);
?>
```

You should get this PHP results

```
Array ( [0] => textsearch [1] => textsearch_1 )
```

In this example the javascript used `onclick()` is not related, but explain on how to get the PHP part instead

Then you can continue to use the array in javascript or PHP way.